# How to toggle class of multiple list items which displayed with *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I display list of different type with the `*ngFor`. What i need is when you click on any type, class `.filtered` should be toggled (if you click on typeA and then on typeB both should have class `.filtered`, if click again on the selected type, class should be removed).

**Component**

```
this.type = ["All", "typeA", "typeB", "typeC", "typeD", "typeE"]
```

**HTML**

```
<li> 
 <a id="filter">Type <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 
 <div class="drop-options tipoOption"> 
   <div *ngFor="let item of type;let i=index" 
    class="drop-option" 
    (click)="isClicked = i;" 
    [class.filtered]="isClicked==i"> 
    <span></span> 
    <p>{{ item }}</p> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
</li>
```

The way it works now, it toggle class only on one type, and deselect from others.

Comment: one approach will be to create a separate loop component and have click event handled in that component and then you can easily toggle individual item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of type;let i=index" 
    class="drop-option" 
    (click)="isClicked[i] = !isClicked[i];" 
    [class.filtered]="isClicked[i]">
```

This assumes the default for each array index starts as false.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, just small question Is it possible to add modification, that when you select option **All** it will deselect (remove class) all selected? Or i need to write a function for that?

Comment: Best way would be to create a function for it that loops through the array and resets the others to false.